# Improving performance of for loop when decimating a buffer

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

I am collecting 16384 double values from a hardware device using a signal processing library.  The 16384 values I receive are the output of a low pass filter.  I want to down sample by a factor of 10.  In other words, I want to keep 1 point out of every 10.  So in general it works like this:

1. I get a buffer from my library when the low pass filter has completed.
2. I then collect 10 of these buffers.
3. When all 10 buffers are collected into one buffer that has 10*16384 doubles I then loop collecting every 10th double from the buffer.  The result is one buffer with 16384 doubles.  This will sent off for the rest of the data processing.

Here is the code:

```
double[] rawData = new double[163840];
int bufferCount = 0;

private void genericReal2_ProcessData(object Sender, Mitov.SignalLab.ProcessRealNotifyArgs Args)
{
    var realbuffer = Args.InBuffer; //get the buffer of processed doubles

    var myData = realbuffer.ToArray(); //must be converted to an array since the data type is not quite an array of doubles.

    Array.Copy(myData, 0, rawData, bufferCount * 16384, 16384);

    bufferCount++;

    if (bufferCount == 10)
    {
        bufferCount = 0;

        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 163840; i += 10) //this loop takes 20ms
        {
            realbuffer[j] = rawData[i];                   
            j++;
        }

        genericReal2.SendData(realbuffer); //send data off for further processing
    }
}
```

The for loop takes about 20ms to run whereas everything else is around 20uS.
So, is there some way I could improve the overall performance of this without using the for loop?

Update**************************
I have determined that all the processing time in the loop is taken assigning realbuffer to rawData.  So I changed this as follows:

```
    private void genericReal2_ProcessData(object Sender, Mitov.SignalLab.ProcessRealNotifyArgs Args)
    {
        double[] finalBuffer = new double[16384];

        var realbuffer = Args.InBuffer; //get the buffer of processed doubles

        var myData = realbuffer.ToArray(); //must be converted to an array since the data type is not quite an array of doubles.

        Array.Copy(myData, 0, rawData, bufferCount * 16384, 16384);

        bufferCount++;

        if (bufferCount == 10)
        {
            bufferCount = 0;

            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 163840; i += 10)
            {
                finalBuffer[j] = rawData[i];
                j++;
            }

             var pointer= realbuffer.Read();
             //I can get a pointer to the realbuffer.
             //It stores 8 bytes for every double value
             how can I copy 16384 8 byte values from finalbuffer to realbuffer?


            genericReal2.SendData(realbuffer); //send data off for further processing
        }
```

Comment: `Mitov.SignalLab.ProcessRealNotifyArgs.InBuffer[j] =` is probably slow. If it has some `FromArray` function, it may be faster, but I really do not know if it has. Either way, the problem is not in this code.

Comment: You could loop the individual chunks instead of all of them at once. This would serve to break up the processing a little bit. Or.. if the size of double isn't required, changing to floats would speed things up in a 32bit environment. Another option could be Parallel.For()

Answer (score 1):

This is solved.  The libraries I use have a function which will assign all values from a double[] to it's internal real buffer

```
 realbuffer.Equals(finalBuffer);
```

This takes 50us...
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting everything and then drop the unnecessary ones. How about dropping those without copying at first step. I mean rather than using Array.Copy just copy the needed ones like;

```
int j = bufferCount * 16384;
for (int i = 0; i < 16384; i += 10)
{
    realbuffer[j++] = rawData[i];
}
```

By doing so you will not need to run the loop inside if statement.

If you cannot change the overall structure of you code due to any condition, you can increase the loop performance by a technique that is used in sorting algorithms . Define your array with the size 163840 + 1. Assign some value to the last position  of your array such as -1 which will not be inside the received data. And change the loop as follows which decreases the number of comparison in the execution of the loop;

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawData[i+=10 ] !=-1; ) 
{
    realbuffer[j] = rawData[i];
    j++;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your first statement would not work since 16384 is not divisible by 10.  I will try the second one.

Comment: You can use padding elements in array to make divisible by 10 and check the performance. It saves significant ticks for some algorithms. You can evaluate if it worths it.

Comment: I'm trying to make some sense out of your second statement.  It is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

You could try putting each buffer into a dictionary and processing them in a for each. Theoretically this should be faster because the arrays will be processed in parallel. 20ms is pretty fast, why the need for such speed?

```
var buffers = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();
```

Then process something like this:

```
var myData = realbuffer.ToArray();

buffers.Add(bufferCount, myData);

if (bufferCount == 10)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(buffers, (buffer) =>
   {
      //process buffer independently
   });
}
```

Comment: "20ms is pretty fast" - for the task given it is not. "why the need for such speed?" - because... it is needed? The dictionary is a bit overkill here, why add such complex structure where array fits? The overhead of parallel foreach would make this solution slower than sequential processing. About 300x slower for the first run and about 3x for all others (the timing was very unstable, but it was never faster than sequential). Btw the offset calculation in ForEach is really awkward.

Comment: I have a fast development machine but there are a lot  of users that may not.  So 20ms may become 40ms, and so on.  The resulting array is sent to a   fast fourier transform and eventually plotted.  Frame rates would no longer become real time.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - a dictionary is a complex object (lol), and I didn't say it would be faster - I thought it was worth a try. The offset difficult - not really...

Comment: Dictionary has ten variables to keep his inner state, among others one array of ints, one array of custom structs and two other collections. Compared with array it is on another level of complexity.